# Gazebo not loading moving joints

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, robot-state-publisher, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I am trying to spawn a urdf file on gazebo but it looks like gazebo is only reading fixed joints. If I change all my moving joints to fixed I can see a tf tree published on the tf topic but if I change back to moving joints it only publishes fixed ones. The spawned model just vibrates while moving the moving joints around randomly. Please help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32008/gazebo-not-loading-moving-joints/) by [OptiX](https://answers.ros.org/users/1535/optix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2012-04-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [OptiX](https://answers.ros.org/users/1535/optix/) on 2012-04-17**:
Thanks hsu it really helps a lot. I got another problem though, when I run my launch file which launches a whole lot of stuff I get these errors: 1. Could not initialize chain object, 2. Could not load models. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Non-fixed joints are not published to tf-tree by default.  One way to do this is to rely on the [gazebo_ros_controller_manager plugin](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_gazebo_plugins#gazebo_controller_manager).  To make this work you have to provide [`<transmission>` elements](http://ros.org/wiki/urdf/XML/Transmission) to your model for each non-fixed joints.

Or you can write a gazebo plugin to publish tf transforms for non-fixed joints, which might be a handy plugin to have around (or ticket this as a feature request).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2